# Compiling the AWS Elastic Beanstalk demo threw exception No Java compiler available

Tags: java, jsp, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm compiling the Amazon Web Services Elastic Beanstalk demo and attempting to run it (locally, on tomcat7) on a fresh install of Arch linux.

Every time, it fails to the console with:

```
Feb 18, 2012 2:31:41 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/TryTwo] threw exception [java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Java compiler available] with root cause
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Java compiler available
at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.createCompiler(JspCompilationContext.java:228)
at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:638)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
```

```
# which java 
/usr/bin/java

# java -version 
java version "1.7.0_03-icedtea"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea7 2.1) (ArchLinux build 7.b147_2.1-1-x86_64)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 22.0-b10, mixed mode)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You might want to try `javac -version` as well to ensure the presence of a Java compiler in fact - presumably it simply isn't installed, see my answer for [an explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9382717/45773) in case.

Comment: javac -version gives "javac 1.7.0_03"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer here: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=135775

The Arch tomcat7 package is broken.

I uninstalled tomcat7:

## pacman -R tomcat7

And then copied the normal Tomcat 7 files from Apache.org to /usr/share/tomcat7

Everything works fine now.

Comment: +1 (and then some ...) for following up with your solution despite the unfortunate bounty timing ;)

Answer (score 3):

[Arch Linux](http://www.archlinux.org/) features the usual distinction between the [Java Runtime Environment (JRE)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Runtime_Environment) package and the [Java Development Kit (JDK)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDK) as shown for other OS in [How to download and install prebuilt OpenJDK packages](http://openjdk.java.net/install/) as well, e.g. for Debian or Ubuntu:

> The openjdk-7-**jre** package contains just the Java Runtime Environment.
>   If you want to develop Java programs then install the openjdk-7-**jdk**
>   package. *[emphasis mine]*

The respective package names of [OpenJDK](http://openjdk.java.net/) are obviously a bit unfortunate and misleading in this regard (though understandable), insofar both packages feature *openjdk* in its name, but only one the actual JDK - the same similarity applies for the Arch Linux [jre7-openjdk](http://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/jre7-openjdk/) and [jdk7-openjdk](http://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/i686/jdk7-openjdk/) package double.

Thus, you'll simply have to install the appropriate JDK package for Arch Linux and should be good to go, i.e. likely *jdk7-openjdk* as per a [Arch Linux Package Database search for jdk](http://www.archlinux.org/packages/?q=jre).

Good luck!

Comment: I have already installed the jdk7-openjdk package: # pacman -S jdk7-openjdk gives "warning: jdk7-openjdk-7.b147_2.1-1 is up to date -- reinstalling"

Comment: I do appreciate your assistance though. here's the entire build output if that helps: http://pastebin.com/N3EdWcgm